# Current flow in the superconducting intermediate state

Tags: superconductivity

The superconducting intermediate state consists of both superconducting and normal regions within the material. I was wondering if the current only flows through the superconducting regions, or also in the normal regions? I'm assuming current flows through the normal regions, since a resistance is measured for the intermediate state and this is done by observing a voltage $V=IR$ across the material. However, current usually flows through regions of less resistance, so shouldn't the current flow only through the superconducting regions? Any and all help is appreciated to solve this little paradox of mine.